# Restore all missing Apps from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell

All the Windows Apps (installed from Windows Store) on my Windows 10 were disappeared. I don't know how, must be because of an update.

That metro-style'd start menu changed to this. Later, I noticed apps like Mail, Stick Notes, Wunderlist and even Windows Store, that were pinned to my taskbar disappeared. I tried searching on Start Menu for those apps but could not find them.

metro-style'd:

[image]

Current:

[image]

Then, after few Google I ***restored Windows Store*** by following [these](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-store-app-missing-windows-10) steps.

1. Download Reinstall-preinstalledApps.zip from Microsoft and extract to any directory.
2. Open PowerShell as admin and entering this command (press **Y**)

   ```
   Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
   ```
3. On powershell, go to the directory where the *Reinstall-preinstalledApps.zip* was extracted, and enter this command

   ```
   .\reinstall-preinstalledApps.ps1 *Microsoft.WindowsStore*
   ```
4. Also used **WSReset.exe** (as admin)
5. Re enabled enforcement for signed PowerShell script

   ```
   Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned
   ```

I also had to reinstall Sticky Notes through *powershell*, using *method 2* of this [blog](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-reset-and-reinstall-sticky-notes-in-windows-10/).

Confusing thing is, now when I search for Wunderlist on Windows Search (Figure index 1), it shows *install app form store*, then when I click on it to go to store, it says App is already installed and gives option to Launch (2). I can launch the app (3), but the icon does not appear on Taskbar (4), if it would then I could pin it there. And the app disappears from my desktop if I minimize it again.

[image]

I do not want to keep reinstalling every apps that are missing. Is there a way through which I can restore all the apps that got disappeared with fewer step, may be through powershell.

Comment: The simplest solution: Reset your computer.  This of course means you have to reinstall your desktop applications.  Worth pointing out that your second image of your start menu actually is normal, you just have clicked on the hamburger button, if you click on it again your start menu will go back to the other mode.

Comment: Clicking on Hamburger does not bring, the previous "metro-styled" menu back or change any mode, it just expand the same layer to show my username, and label for Settings and Power icon, regarding Resetting computer, i think that would be the last thing i want to do right now. I have lots of desktop application and project going on, that i can't spend time on reinstalling all those application again.

Comment: I believe this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWsSt.jpg) is from 1511 not 1607, and you can only defer an feature update 6 months.  Which means, if both images were from your own system, this can't possible be from a feature update.  Which means the problem is unlikely caused by a an update.  Have you consider using a restore point?  You can also manually update to 1703 (today) and see if that helps.  The disadvantage of this is you will until April 11th be on an Insider Preview build.

Comment: That image was from google, and just meant for the style of menu I was trying to describe on my question. I had no screen shots of how menu used to look on my PC, but from what i remember it was similar to that. I have not used restore point. I think I'll try that if I couldn't find any powershell scripts.

Comment: did you try this in powershell ?: `Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"`

Comment: @LateGameReviewer yes, that didn't work, I checked by rebooting the system after that script.

Comment: try to do an upgrade. so download windows 10 on a usb stick, and just do an upgrade and select the "keep everything" option. this should fix the problem and you wont lose anything, no files, no settings, nothing.

Comment: I think I have the latest Windows from my MSDN. Upgraded in January and have been updating on every minor update, I am also in Slow ring in Insider Builds.